# Why is the SR Flip flop edge enabled

Tags: flipflop, latch

I'm struggling to understand the diference between a Latch and a SR Flip Flop, I know that a latch is level activated, and the SR Flip Flop is edge activated but if the circuit is the same, why is the behavior diferent?

I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1QBxTeVaNs) from Neso Academy, I really don't know why the latch becomes edge active if I use a clock.

If i send a 1 the latch is active, so why isn't the SR flip flop active when the clock is 1?

Am I missing something or is there an error in the video?

Comment: if the circuit is the same, then the behavior cannot be different

Comment: exactly that's why I don't understand the video, he said  "the circuit will act as a Flip flop when we have clock in place of enabled" I'm not sure if I am missing something because Neso Acadamy seems to be a good channel

Comment: The term 'latch' and 'flip-flop' are rather mixed up. Even in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29) they talk about "a flip-flop or latch". Engineers, like me, who have to deal with registers and latches make a clear distinction. What they show in that video is **not** what we experts call a 'latch'. So again: be careful what you find on YouTube.

Comment: I suggest you ignore the video and look for other resources. Note that the terms "latch" and "flip-flop" are not standardized.

Comment: the `clock in place of enable` statement is kind of ridiculous in that context ... it is exactly the same thing .... perhaps what should have been said is `if you think of the signal as a clock instead of enable`

Comment: There's an underlying mechanism to make flip-flop be edge-triggered (unlike a latch, which is level). You can create an edge-triggered FF by having two D-latches in a row (master-slave configuration). See this: http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Digital/dig53.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time when SR latches are edge-sensitive is the release of SR input contention.

When both Set and Reset are active then both outputs Q & Q* are asserted "1".
Then after the 1st input {S,R} edge is removed from the active state, only the corresponding output {S=>Q, R=>Q!} will change.

A clock enabled SR Latch is a MISNOMER if called a Flip Flop as it not a  Flip Flop {D,T or JK}  Also this would cause an unstable output if both S=R=active when Clock enable goes low.

[image]

Conclusion:  Youtube video is wrong.